# ¿Cómo poner el label de un input tipo radio debajo?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

Buen día amigos,

Tengo el siguiente problema, debo poner el label debajo de cada input hasta ahí todo bien el problema es que no quedan alieneados, me muestra lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:
https://jsfiddle.net/cvaqpxby/1/

De antemano mil gracias!

Answer (score 4):

Una opción sería personalizar los `inputs` y `label` respectivos, utilizando display y margin para centrar el contenido y darle el posicionamiento que deseas

```css
input[type=radio] {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <label><input type="radio" name="radioset" />1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radioset" />2</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radioset" />3</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radioset" />4</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radioset" />5</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radioset" />6</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radioset" />7</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radioset" />8</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radioset" />9</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radioset" />10</label>
</div>
```

Nos comentas si te sirve

Answer (score 0):

Mira con estas modificaciones quedaria centrada, ya solo hay que definir si quieres que los elementos se desborden o no cuando los elementos superen el tamaño del contenedor padre.

```
    .radio-change{
         margin-left: -5px;
         position: relative;
     left: 20p;
     display: flex !important;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center !important;
     width: 11%;

    }

    .radio-change  label{
    min-height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    cursor: pointer;
    }


  .inputs-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: left;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es lo mínimo posible para lograr eso.

```
.inputs-container{
  display: flex;
}

.inputs-container .input-question {
  text-align: center;
}
 .inputs-container .input-question input {
   display: block;
   min-width: 25px;
}
```

¡Saludos!